# Looping through dynamic form fields and inserting into database

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server

I have a from for adding a persons dependents with first name, last name and i am using jquery multiFieldExtender plugin (http://vipullimbachiya.com/jQuery/Plugins/MultiField/2/index.htm)  to add additional fields dynamically. What this does is it adds an additional first name, last name field to my form when you click on "Add Another Dependent". I have altered the script so it does not add increments to the name element and only the id element. Here is the mark up generated:

```
<input id="fnameD" name="fnameD[]" placeholder="First Name"   type="text"><br />
<input id="lnameD" name="lnameD[]" placeholder="Last Name"   type="text">

//additional field looks like below
<input id="fnameD_0" name="fnameD[]" placeholder="First Name"   type="text"><br />
<input id="lnameD_0" name="lnameD[]" placeholder="Last Name"   type="text">

//and another additional field looks like below
<input id="fnameD_1" name="fnameD[]" placeholder="First Name"   type="text"><br />
<input id="lnameD_1" name="lnameD[]" placeholder="Last Name"   type="text">
```

As you can see the id gets incremented with each element group added. I am trying to submit this to an ajax file and loop through the fname, lname posted data and insert it into MS SQL database. My code is below. I get no errors and nothing gets inserted.

My form page.

```
<?php require 'core/init.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form action="" id="application" method="post" /><!-- Form Name -->
<div id="dependentDetails" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<div class="control-group">
  <p class="lead">Dependent Details</p>
  <label class="control-label"></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="fnameD" name="fnameD[]" placeholder="First Name"   type="text"><br />
  <input id="lnameD" name="lnameD[]" placeholder="Last Name"   type="text">
  </div>
</div>
</div><!-- dependentDetails -->
<button  name="submit"  class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
</div>

<script>
   $('#application').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();   
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "core/classes/ajax_test.php",  
            data:{data: $('form').serialize()},
            success: function(response){
            $("#result").html(response);
      }
    });
});
</script>


<script src="js/jquery.multiFieldExtender-2.0.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dependentDetails").EnableMultiField({
  linkText: 'Add Another Dependent',
  removeLinkText: '<span style="color:#FF0000;">Remove above Dependent</span>',
  confirmationMsgOnRemove: 'Are you sure you wish to remove the this dependent?'
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My ajax file.

```
<?php
require('../init.php');
                    if (isset($_POST['fnameD'])) {
                            for ( $i=0;$i<count($_POST['fnameD']);$i++) {
                            $fnameD = $_POST['fnameD'][$i];
                            $lnameD = $_POST['lnameD'][$i];

                            $query = $dbP->prepare("INSERT INTO dbo.testMulti(fnameD, lnameD)VALUES (?, ?)");
                                     $query->bindValue(1, $fnameD);
                                     $query->bindValue(2, $lnameD);
                                                try{
                                                    $query->execute();
                                                    echo 'got the data';
                                                }catch(PDOException $e){
                                                    die($e->getMessage());
                                                }

                            }
                    }

?>
```

Here is what I get when I add Mike Smith, Bob Smith and submit and print_r($_POST);

```
Array ( [data] => fnameD%5B%5D=Bob&lnameD%5B%5D=Smith&fnameD%5B%5D=Mike&lnameD%5B%5D=Smith )
```

What am I missing or doing wrong? Am I looping through jquery serialized posted data correct. If not, how do you do this properly?

Comment: *why* do you serialize your data?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you're assigning the serialized data to a single variable, try to submit the formdata as is, or use the ajaxSubmit function from [Ajax Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

```
$("#application").ajaxSubmit({url: 'core/classes/ajax_test.php', type: 'post'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want serializeArray() instead of serialize()

```
data:{data: $('form').serializeArray()},
```

Comment: you actually made me think of what I was posting which led to my answer +1 for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I got it...I changed:

```
data:{data: $('form').serialize()},
```

to this

```
data:$('form').serialize(),
```

works like a champ!